# Run my background service at a specific time and periodically using JobScheduler

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I want to run a background service to fetch new data every 24 hours starting from 11:45 PM using JobScheduler, the problem is that I can't find how to tell the jobSheduler that my service should start running at 11:45 PM ?

```
 private void constructJob() {
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, new ComponentName(this, TestService.class));
    builder.setPeriodic(24*60*60*1000) //24 hours * 60 min * 60 sec * 1000
    .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .build();

}
```

PS : I avoid to use AlarmManager, I want to benefit from the advantges of the jobScheduler API features like :
*combining jobs so that battery consumption is reduced. 
*making handling uploads easier as it handles automatically the unreliability of the network.
*Surviving the application restarts

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find how to tell the jobSheduler that my service should start running at 11:45 PM ?

That is because that is not supported. `JobScheduler` periodic jobs are designed to be inexact, for maximal power savings.

Comment: thank you for your replying,  during my search for a solution I found this discussion [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/52) some kind of workaround to get the job done (Ansh1234's response) but the idea stills not very clear, may you can help me to understand it